# Regex Question: separate string at the last comma in string

Tags: r, regex

My string pattern is as follows:

1233 fox street, omaha NE ,69131-7233
Jeffrey Jones, 666 Church Street, Omaha NE ,69131-72339
Betty Davis, LLC, 334 Aloha Blvd., Fort Collins CO ,84444-00333
,1233 Decker street, omaha NE ,69131-7233

I need to separate the above string into four variables: *name*, *address*, *city_state*, *zipcode*.

Since the pattern has three to four  commas, I am starting at the right to separate the field into multiple fields.

*rubular.com* says the pattern  `("(,\\d.........)$")))` or the pattern `",\d.........$"` will match the zipcode at the end of the string.

*regex101.com*, finds neither of the above patterns comes up with a match.

When I try to separate with:

```
#need to load pkg:tidyr for the `separate`
```

function
library(tidyr)
separate(street_add, c("street_add2", "zip", sep=  ("(,\d.........)$")))

or with:

```
separate(street_add, c("street_add2", "zip", sep=  (",\d.........$")))
```

In both scenarios, R splits at the first comma in the string.
How do I split the string into segments?
Thank you.

Comment: Re: citing `rubular.com` ...You should realize that the syntax for regular expressions in R is different than in some other languages. Maybe Ruby has the same weirdness as R (I don't know if this is the case), but if so you should say so. Otherwise you should rely on R-specific authorities for example code for R-regex patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```r
sep=",(?=[^,]*$)"
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/JhFPBr/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```r
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^,]*                    any character except: ',' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: Ryszard: Thank you for the code and the explanation.  :)

Comment: Thank you Ryszard.  I'm still learning my way around here.

Comment: That website is only useful if the person using it understands that R needs modifications  for escape sequences.